# How to render items of a section in a single row in Listview of react native?

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-listview

I am following [this](http://moduscreate.com/react-native-listview-with-section-headers/) tutorial to make a Listview with sections in `react-native`. However I want my elements of a particular section to be separated in column-wise fashion instead of rendering them in separate rows. I tried to change the `flex` direction but wasn't able to do it.

In my `render` function, I have:

```
return(
   <ListView
       dataSource = {this.state.dataSource}
       renderRow  = {this.renderRow}
       renderSectionHeader = {this.renderSectionHeader}
       style={styles.listview}
   />
```

`listview` is as follows:

```
listView: {
  margin: 10,
  flexDirection: 'row'
  flexWrap: 'wrap'
}
```

and `renderRow` is given by:

```
return (
    <View>
      <Button onPress={this._setModalVisible.bind(this,true)}>
        <Image source={image} style={{width:50,height:60}}/>
      </Button>
    </View>
);
```

What I want is that all the `Buttons` of a particular section to be displayed in single row but I am not able to do it. How to achieve this task?

Comment: Can you show the code you have tried?

Comment: Updated my question with the code.

Answer (score 1):

You could restructure your list of items nesting the items you want in one row together

```
items = [
   item, item, item, [item, item, item]
]
```

and do the checking in the renderRow function to render them at once

```
renderRow(row){
    if(Array.isArray(row)){
        var _renderRow = this.renderRow;
        return (
            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                {row.map((item) => _renderRow(item))}
            <View>);
    }else{
        return (
            <View>
              <Button onPress={this._setModalVisible.bind(this,true)}>
                <Image source={image} style={{width:50,height:60}}/>
              </Button>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```